# How to put result of query in a variable?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, while-loop

I'm playing just a little bit with PHP/PDO and I think I have a quite easy question for you.

This is my sql `$query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1');` and after this I have put a while-loop:

```
while($r = $query->fetch()) {
    echo '<img src=', $r['imagepath'], '>';
}
```

This code works perfectly for me but now I would like to put the result of the fetch-method into a variable and output it in a easy way in my html-table afterwards between php tags, in preference to put the whole while loop between the html tags. This is just ugly and I don't think that this is the proper way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function as shown below with **`EXTR_SKIP`** flag.

```
while($r = $query->fetch()) {
  extract($r, EXTR_SKIP); 
  echo "<img src='{$imagepath}'>";
}
```

Also, as a side note. Refrain generally from using `SELECT *` in your query, generally for performance related-issue.  At the same time, I would rewrite your query as:

```
$result = $handler->query("SELECT imagename, imagepath FROM ... LIMIT 1" , PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

extract($result, EXTR_SKIP); 
echo "<img src='{$imagePath}'>";
```

Comment: OP wants a solution where the while loop does not have to be in the HTML. Not possible, since the amount of rows in the HTML table are dependent on the MySQL result set, but you should consider addressing that in your answer.

Comment: @CodeVolunteer your quest is not clear, how many rows do you expect? The `LIMIT 1` suggests, you only have one row .. right?

Comment: No, I have more than one. But I started with web development barely 2 months ago and I spent the most time for html, wp, bootstrap/css.

I just want to work for the basics right now. You helped me so far, so thank you :-)

This is certainly one out of 100 questions that I'll post in the future^^

Comment: @CodeVolunteer Good luck. You can come to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php and I'll help you when I can.